# How do I install kernel 5.15.7=> on Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri?

Tags: package-management, kernel, dependencies, linux-headers

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 *impish indri*.

For some specific hardware support, I'm advised to upgrade to kernel 5.16 (mainline). I tried manually [installing the `.deb` files](https://9to5linux.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-16-on-ubuntu-or-linux-mint) and installing them using `dpkg -i`. However, I'm getting dependency issues:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic : Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
```

I ran `sudo apt -f install` and it suggested removing the 5.16 kernel packages. So, I removed them for now.

How can I install kernel 5.16 on Ubuntu 21.10 *impish indri*? I've all the repositories enabled with no additional PPAs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to manually installing `libssl3`, is to pin that package. Pinning is described in the [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

You need to edit 3 files. Create them first with `sudo touch <filename>` if they don't yet exist. This makes sure that permissions and ownership are set correctly.

---

**`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu`**

```
APT::Default-Release "impish";
```

This makes `impish` the default Ubuntu release to install packages from.

---

**`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-jammy.list`**

```
deb http://mirror.example.com/ubuntu/ jammy main
```

This adds the `jammy` (22.04) repository. Ubuntu is not actually using it by default, because of the value of `APT::Default-Release`. I repeat, and I can't stress this enough: Ubuntu will never ever install any package from this (or any other) `jammy` repository, unless one of these conditions is true:

- you explicitly tell `apt` to install a specific version that only exists in the `jammy` repository (this supposes that you know what you are doing!)
- a (specific version of a) package is pulled in as a dependency
- you create an exception to the general rule using pinning - see next file.
- the package does not exist in the main Ubuntu repository and only exists in an added third-party repository, like a PPA.

---

**`/etc/apt/preferences.d/libssl3`**

```
Package: libssl3
Pin: release n=jammy
Pin-Priority: 900
```

This gives a higher priority to the package `libssl3` coming from the `jammy` repository, and only that package. So for all packages, `impish` is the default, and for `libssl3` there is an exception.

---

Now run `sudo apt update`. Don't run it before you have edited all 3 files!

To see which packages are going to be installed, run `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy libssl3
libssl3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.0.1-0ubuntu1 900
        500 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As you can see, there is only one installation candidate for `libssl3`, from the `jammy` repository.

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-image-generic
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: 5.13.0.35.44
  Candidate: 5.13.0.35.44
  Version table:
     5.15.0.22.24 500
        500 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.13.0.35.44 990
        990 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages
        990 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.13.0.19.30 990
        990 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages
```

The package `linux-image-generic` is available:

- at version `5.15.0.22.24`, in `jammy/main`, with priority `500`
- at version `5.13.0.35.44`, in `impish-updates/main` and `impish-security/main`, with priority `990`
- at version `5.13.0.19.30` (the original version from the USB or DVD installer at release), in `impish/main`, with priority `990`.

The `***` indicates which version will be installed.

---

In my particular use case, I had to install many kernels: `5.13`, `5.14`, `5.15`, `5.16`, `5.17`. I currently have 35 kernels installed:

```
$ ls -1 /boot/initrd* | wc --lines
35
```

To demonstrate that `libssl` is automatically installed as a dependency when needed, I install the Ubuntu kernel `5.15.0-22-generic`, which is also from Jammy:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-5.15.0-22-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Donesudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-5.15.0-22-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl3 linux-headers-5.15.0-22
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl3 linux-headers-5.15.0-22 linux-headers-5.15.0-22-generic linux-image-5.15.0-22-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-22-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-22-generic
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 103 MB of archives.
After this operation, 565 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl3 linux-headers-5.15.0-22
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl3 linux-headers-5.15.0-22 linux-headers-5.15.0-22-generic linux-image-5.15.0-22-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-22-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-22-generic
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 103 MB of archives.
After this operation, 565 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

As you can see, the package `libssl3` is automatically pulled in as a dependency.

If one does not need a 5.15 kernel, then one simply installs `libssl3` directly:

```
$ sudo apt install --yes libssl3
```

---

With all of this, one still hasn't installed a mainline kernel, and I strongly agree with all warnings regarding permanently adding a kernel PPA. As an alternative, you can use the [Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) (UMKI), a graphical tool to install the latest mainline kernels. It fetches the list from the mainline kernel PPA, without actually needing to add the PPA to your sources. You can install the `.deb` package from the GitHub releases pages, or do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

If you don't like (or can't use) a GUI, it also has a CLI:

```
$ mainline
mainline 1.0.15
Distribution: Ubuntu 21.10
Architecture: amd64
Running kernel: 5.13.0-22-generic

mainline 1.0.15 - Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer

Syntax: mainline <command> [options]

Commands:

  --check             Check for kernel updates
  --notify            Check for kernel updates and notify current user
  --list              List all available mainline kernels
  --list-installed    List installed kernels
  --install-latest    Install latest mainline kernel
  --install-point     Install latest point update for current series
  --install <name>    Install specified mainline kernel(1)
  --uninstall <name>  Uninstall specified kernel(2)
  --uninstall-old     Uninstall kernels older than the running kernel
  --download <name>   Download specified kernels(2)
  --clean-cache       Remove files from application cache

Options:

  --include-unstable  Include unstable and RC releases
  --hide-unstable     Hide unstable and RC releases
  --debug           Enable verbose debugging output
  --yes             Assume Yes for all prompts (non-interactive mode)
  --user            Override user

Notes:
(1) A version string taken from the output of --list
(2) One or more version strings (comma-separated) taken from the output of --list
```

For example, `sudo mainline --install-latest --include-unstable` currently installs mainline kernel `5.17.0-rc7`.

---

I have installed 12 different kernels so far using UMKI, and I'm very happy with it.

This method is safe as long as you follow the steps above exactly, only to install `libssl`. Don't trust it? Fair enough. Try it out for yourself in a safe environment like a virtual machine. Still don't trust it? Remove (or comment out) the file **`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-jammy.list`** right after you have installed `libssl`, and run `sudo apt update` again.

---

One more thing to finish: if and when you decide to upgrade from `impish` to `jammy`, then you only need to delete (or comment) the 3 files **`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu`**, **`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-jammy.list`**, **`/etc/apt/preferences.d/libssl3`** before starting the upgrade. The first one is a must, the other two are some housekeeping because you no longer need them.

---

This answer is referenced in [Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline/blob/master/README.md) [GitHub issue 127](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline/issues/127) and forms the basis of their [wiki page on installing libssl](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline/wiki/Install-libssl3). You can also read about it on [my blog](https://amedee.be/install-libssl3-on-systems-before-jammy/).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I admit I should have given the whole information at once. I apologise. I have upvoted and accepted your answer as it seems more reasonable as compared to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the GitHub issue. Also, let's clear this thread by deleting these comments as they are creating more confusion. BTW in the GitHub issue I saw the link to your blog, to me on my browser, it shows as 503 site blocked..

Comment: Is the exact message "Your access to this site has been limited by the site owner"? What is your IP (just the first two bytes) and/or what is your country? I'm blocking some countries because I'm getting to many hacking attempts.

Comment: link mirror.servers.com is broken

Comment: @PavelNiedoba it's an example, please check the edited version. `example.com` is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Well, because, for some reason, I had this answer downvoted... but after re-reading it I found the research useful and worthy of an upvote, and to retract my downvote I did a minor edit and upvoted. I apologise...

Comment: @Error404 ok I see thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**: You can manually install the package from 22.04 repositories.

Ubuntu mainline kernel 5.15.7+ and 5.16 bumps the requirement from `libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0)` to `libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1)`. However, package `libssl3` is **not** [available for Ubuntu 21.10 *impish indri*.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl3&searchon=names&suite=impish&section=all). It's only [available for Ubuntu 22.04 *jammy jellyfish*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl3&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all) which is not yet released.

`libssl3` further depends on `libc6`>=`2.34` and `debconf` which **are available in 21.10 repositories.**

So, you can manually install `libssl3` from Jammy Jellyfish repositories. You'll not have any problems in doing that unless you've done something really strange with your system.

To install `libssl3` on Ubuntu 21.10, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6 debconf
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl3_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl3_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Now, you can install the kernel 5.16 on Ubuntu 21.10 without any issues.

Keep in mind that mainline kernels have not been tested with their release of Ubuntu. That means YOU are doing the testing. You may encounter the unexpected. Ubuntu prefers stable LTS kernels over unstable mainline kernels.

You can use the following commands to install the unsigned kernel 5.16 (*don't worry about unsigned unless you are using secure boot*):

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.0-051600_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-modules-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Folks who discover this method should keep in mind that PPA kernels have not been tested with their release of Ubuntu. That means YOU are doing the testing. You may encounter the unexpected. Or it might work just fine. We all hope for the best, but when you wander the untracked wilderness, you should be prepared to encounter a bear.

Comment: It's true, but for a time I used Arch Linux which uses mainline kernels very shortly after release and I never had any issues. Maybe I was lucky.