# Wifi Adapter not working Ubuntu 21.10 fresh install in Asus laptop

Tags: wireless, laptop, asus

I am not all that new to Ubuntu (have been using it for 20 years now), but as all good friends, sometimes it still manages to surprise me.

After fresh install (Ubuntu 21.10 in an Asus ROG laptop) I cannot seem to get the wifi to work. I do not see a wifi icon and in settings-> wifi I get the wifi adapter not found error.

I am not an expert in Ubuntu (just a long term user) and I realize I know very little about how the wifi works.

As far as I can tell, the system is unable to find the wifi controller (I believe there isn't one).

I happen to know that the wifi controller does exist and works because this computer came with a preinstalled windows (not there anymore) with which I could use the wifi without problems. At this moment I am connected via wired connection which also works fine.

Any help would be very welcome.

I run the wifi diagnostic script that I found in the forum with the following results.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Mar 2022 14:35 JST +0900

Booted last: 30 Mar 2022 00:00 JST +0900

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.13.0-39-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 15:35:05 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]

0000:2c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1043:205f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8125

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
iwlwifi               380928  0
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              897024  1 iwlwifi
asus_wmi               40960  3 asus_nb_wmi,hid_asus,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  5 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  53248  3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp44s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp44s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 133.24.25.175/23 brd 133.24.25.255 scope global noprefixroute enp44s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::27d7:c858:c237:83df/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp44s0   no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 133.24.24.254 dev enp44s0 proto static metric 100 
133.24.24.0/23 dev enp44s0 proto kernel scope link src 133.24.25.175 metric 100 
133.24.24.0/23 via 133.24.24.254 dev enp44s0 proto static metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp44s0 scope link metric 1000 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         727       1  0 14:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp44s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8125
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 9.008.00-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp44s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:2c:00.0/net/enp44s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:2c:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp44s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       74ab3dfa-6d40-3a80-ac15-e5d79d5a2286
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         133.24.25.175/23
IP4.GATEWAY:                            133.24.24.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 133.24.24.0/23, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 133.24.24.254, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 133.24.24.0/23, nh = 133.24.24.254, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             133.24.61.2
IP4.DNS[2]:                             133.24.61.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::27d7:c858:c237:83df/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   74ab3dfa-6d40-3a80-ac15-e5d79d5a2286 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Tokyo (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp44s0   no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp44s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    2.119629] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.120490] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
[    2.648896] enp44s0: 0xffffa491011b0000, <MAC 'enp44s0' [IF1]>, IRQ 18
[    3.540607] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    8.408556] r8125: enp44s0: link up
[    8.408565] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp44s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Hello. A good start to any question is an accurate version. There is no Ubuntu 21.

Comment: There may be something going on in your hardware. How is the computer itself? Did the install process have any unusual errors? You may need to instruct your device to set the wifi to "up" telling your hardware to function. Try iwlist to see if any networks are picked up at all. Try nmcli to connect to a specified network. nmtui (Curses) may also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device, 8086:51f0, is not covered in the version of the driver *iwlwifi* included in the default 5.13 kernel included in Ubuntu 21.10. You can confirm this with:

```
modinfo iwlwifi | grep 51f0
```

It returns blank.

This thread suggests that it is covered in kernel version 5.17 and later. https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1846969.html

You can install 5.17 with:

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.1/amd64/linux-headers-5.17.1-051701-generic_5.17.1-051701.202203280950_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.1/amd64/linux-headers-5.17.1-051701_5.17.1-051701.202203280950_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.1/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.17.1-051701-generic_5.17.1-051701.202203280950_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.1/amd64/linux-modules-5.17.1-051701-generic_5.17.1-051701.202203280950_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

The driver also requires firmware:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-68.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @chili555, that worked perfectly.

I did need to install libsl3 additionally as otherwise I had unmet dependencies.

I did it using the instructions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389585/how-do-i-install-kernel-5-15-7-on-ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri)

Comment: Thanks for your update. This will help many others with this very new device. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem with the same device (8086:51f0) but on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.15.0. Had trouble upgrading the kernel and was also a bit skeptical of the solution, as this message suggests that kernel 5.17rc8 has some issues loading the firmware: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1847049.html

Instead I followed the suggestion in this other post and it worked right away: [Ubuntu 22.04, no WIFI on Alienware x17 R2 with Killer 6E - AX1675 Wifi and Bluetooth card - Bluetooth working fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419344/ubuntu-22-04-no-wifi-on-alienware-x17-r2-with-killer-6e-ax1675-wifi-and-bluet)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

(reboot then check if module is properly loaded)

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```