# Ubuntu 22.04, no WIFI on Alienware x17 R2 with Killer 6E - AX1675 Wifi and Bluetooth card - Bluetooth working fine

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, iwlwifi

Ubuntu 22.04 is not seeing WIFI on an AX1675 card, but bluetooth is working.

Some folks have suggested adding the AX210 firmware for iwlwifi, but Ubuntu 22.04 has this firmware already installed in /lib/firmware.

```
sudo dmesg | fgrep -i iwl
```

reveals:

```
[   16.024768] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.026718] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 51f0/1671, rev=0x370, rfid=0x2010d000
[   16.026727] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated - thank you.

Fixed by installing backport-iwlwifi-dkms per chili555's suggestion.

After installing and rebooting, the:

```
sudo dmesg | fgrep -i iwl
```

yields:

```
[   27.931699] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   27.931702] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[   28.109451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   28.111413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-73.ucode failed with error -2
[   28.111422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[   28.113164] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   28.113173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[   28.113504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 so-a0-gf-a0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   28.314108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1675s 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (211NGW), REV=0x370
[   28.484533] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded PNVM version 05a8dfca
[   28.500140] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x2010d000
[   28.612271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 3c:21:9c:47:92:30
[   28.628188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Reboot and show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: chili555 - installing the backport-iwlwifi-dkms package followed by a reboot did the trick (thank you!).  For posterity, I included the results of dmesg | grep iwl in the original post.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Comment: I am also running Ubuntu 22.04 on Alienware x17 r2. My AX1675 WiFi driver was not detected either. Running the first two commands worked for me too.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is anyone else encountering stability issues with this fix? when wifi is enabled getting hard crash with everything becoming unresponsive, disable wifi and everything works fine