# Installation of Ubuntu 20.04LTS and 22.04LTS fails on my MSI Creator Z16 A12UET core i7 12th gen

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, msi, intel-cpu

I have tried severally to install ubuntu desktop on my MSI pc (model stated above) but it always fails run after. The installation completes without error but it always fails to work that is, boot to show the desktop. I am new to linux so I can only try to fix errors with documented clear steps and so far I have not found any. I follow the installation procedure on the ubuntu page yet it does not work.
I tried the ubuntu 22.04 bootable flash drive on an older hp intel corei5 8th gen. everything work fine.
Keep in mind, I added another SSD for the ubuntu so its not going to be on same SSD with my windows
I would appreciate any help to get this running on my MSI. thanks in advance

Comment: With a 12th gen CPU always prefer the newer release so forget about 20.04. Then you also have a very recent Nvidia graphics that needs proprietary drivers and to complicate things further you're, apparently, trying to dual-boot with the preinstalled Windows 11. In order for the proprietary drivers to work you need either (1) disable Secure Boot in UEFI (you can't because Windows 11 requires it unlike previous version) or (2) use mokutil to sign the drivers (during the instillation if you select the option to install 3rd party drivers it should pop-up a dialog for that purpose (...)

Comment: (...) Did you perhaps ignore it? That would explain why the desktop fails to load, if that's what's happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried all the steps you high lighted before but i missed the part of downloading and installing third party software but my WiFi was not detected. so, i used USB tethering to connect to the internet.
My desktop works fine now but my WiFi does not even when i see the adapter listed when i use the lshw command. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: following this link i was able to fix the wifi issue too
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419344/ubuntu-22-04-no-wifi-on-alienware-x17-r2-with-killer-6e-ax1675-wifi-and-bluet