# Network unclaimed on ubuntu 22.04.1 acer swift sf314-512

Tags: 22.04, internet, iwlwifi

I have recently bought a new Acer Swift SF314-512 Laptop and installed ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop. The wifi works fine on windows, but on the ubuntu install it does not work.

```
lshw -C network
```

outputs:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVI WiFi
    vendor: Intel corporation
    physical id: 14.3
    bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
    version: 01
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33Mhz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: iomemory:600-Sff memory:603c2b4000-603c2b7fff
```

This seemed similar to ([22.04.1 Network Unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed)) which suggested installing linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic. So I did this (and also had to install linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic and linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic) but it made no difference. Some other outputs I have seen suggested by other questions:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

outputs:

```
[    3.396430] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 51f0/1672, rev=0x370, rfid=0x2010d000
[    3.396475] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

So, how do I configure it and what is error -22?

If I run `rflist kill all` all the answers are 'no'. If I run

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

it outputs:

```
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel corporation Alder Lake-P PCI CNVI WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
          Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1672]
          Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
```

Some other questions have suggested it is something to do with boot settings (e.g. disabling fast boot or secure boot). So I did this and it made no difference. I also don't think it is to do with boot as if I boot directly from the USB containing the ubuntu image it has the same issue. I have also tried installing Ubuntu 20.04.5 instead and it also doesn't work.

If there is any more information that would help diagnose the issue please let me know. I'm feeling pretty desperate here.

Comment: It is 22.04.1 desktop. I will edit the question to fix the typos. I also tried 20.04.5 desktop.

Comment: Just FYI:  The Ubuntu 20.04.5 Desktop was a *respin* using the GA kernel (5.15) from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; ie. expecting different results from that ISO if it relates to kernel/kernel modules (aka *drivers*) was unlikely.

Comment: @guiverc Okay, that is handy to know. I might try 20.04.1. Will take me a while to download, create a boot disc and install though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi Adapter not working Ubuntu 21.10 fresh install in Asus laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399951/wifi-adapter-not-working-ubuntu-21-10-fresh-install-in-asus-laptop)

Comment: @chill555 That requires internet so I was unable to test. However, I bought a USB to ethernet adapter and connected to ethernet so I could download and install various things. I tried what was suggested in that question to no avail. However, I ended up doing something similar to the answer provided here and I have it working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This device was not supported by the 5.15 kernel.

Now Ubuntu 22.04 has the 5.19 HWE kernel. You can install it by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

Reboot with the new kernel and test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't able to do things like this originally as it requires internet (which is what I was trying to fix). However, prior to seeing this answer I bought a usb to ethernet adaptor and ran 
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic and sudo apt upgrade, rebooted and it works. I think this is very similar to what you have suggested.

Comment: Exactly, if this package was installed, a regular update should have installed the new kernel.