# wifi and sound is not working after i install ubuntu 22.04 in Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiF

Tags: sound, iwlwifi

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0244
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network unclaimed on ubuntu 22.04.1 acer swift sf314-512](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455755/network-unclaimed-on-ubuntu-22-04-1-acer-swift-sf314-512)